# C-equivalent of the 'setw' function

Tags: c

In c++, setw function is used to set the number of characters to be used as the field width for the next insertion operation. Is there any function in C, I mean, in standard c library, which does the same thing?

Comment: This may be the first time I've seen someone who understands how to use iostream formatters and not how to do the equivalent thing with `printf`... it's nearly always the other way around. :)

Comment: Yeah, I run into the same things all the time.  I learned the c++ style iostream formatters in college, but we use c-style at work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`printf ("%5d", 42);`

Will print 42 using 5 spaces. Read the man pages of printf to understand how character padding, overflow and other nuances work.

EDIT:
Some examples -

```
int x = 4000;
printf ("1234567890\n");
printf ("%05d\n", x);
printf ("%d\n", x);
printf ("%5d\n", x);
printf ("%2d\n", x);
```

Gives the output

```
1234567890
04000
4000
 4000
4000
```

Notice that the `%2d` was too small to handle the number passed to it, yet still printed the entire value.

Comment: Note that placing a `-` in front of the padding number will cause the output to align to the left.  For example, `printf("%-7s, "12345");` will print `12345__` where the `_` is a space.  This is opposed to `printf("%7s, "12345");` which will give you `__12345`.

[Related Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/276869/1214700)

Answer (score 5):

No, since the stream used in C doesn't maintain state the way the stream object does.

You need to specify with e.g. `printf()` using a suitable formatting code.

Comment: could you specify how could I do that? I need the equivalent formatting of 'setw(2)'......

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to define the format string as a variable:

```
char print_format[] = "%5d"; printf(print_format, 42);
```

The above is similar to C++ `setw`, in that you can set the contents of the variable before printing.  Many occasions require dynamic formatting of the output.  This is one method to achieve it.

Answer (score -2):

`setw` Manipulator: 
This manipulator sets the minimum field width on output. The syntax is: 
`setw(x)` 
Here `setw` causes the number or string that follows it to be printed within a field of `x` characters wide and `x` is the argument set in `setw` manipulator. The header file that must be included while using `setw` manipulator is 
Sample Code

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 #include <iomanip> 
  
 void main( )
 {
 int x1=12345,x2= 23456, x3=7892;
 cout << setw(8) << "Exforsys" << setw(20) << "Values" << endl
         << setw(8) << "E1234567" << setw(20)<< x1 << endl
         << setw(8) << "S1234567" << setw(20)<< x2 << endl
         << setw(8) << "A1234567" << setw(20)<< x3 << endl;
 }
```

Comment: this is not the c equivilent

Comment: This is not a valid answer. Not c equivalent.