# How to reformat my C output?

Tags: c, io

With

```
fprintf(f,"%d %d %d\n",m,l,k);
```

I got

```
8 0 98
8 1 98
8 2 98
9 0 98
9 1 98
9 2 98
10 0 98
10 1 98
10 2 98
11 0 98
11 1 98
11 2 98
12 0 98
12 1 98
12 2 98
13 0 98
13 1 98
```

What I really want is that each line has same format,like this

```
9  2 98
10 0 98
```

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187149/c-equivalent-of-the-setw-function

Comment: @Jeyaram Yes,I got it.

Comment: Sorry this is a well documented aspect, I was have tempted to copy and paste a "Let me google that for you" link. [External Link](http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output) or [External Link 2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) or [External Link 3](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code

```
fprintf(f,"%2d %d %2d\n",m,l,k);
```

yields:

```
9  2 98
10 0 98
```

Comment: Why -2d not 2d only?

Comment: Well, I did not know that, `%2d` is really what you need.