# Variable sized padding in printf

Tags: c, formatting, printf

Is there a way to have a variable sized padding in `printf`?

I have an integer which says how large the padding is:

```
void foo(int paddingSize) {
    printf("%...MyText", paddingSize);
}
```

This should print out `### MyText` where the paddingSize should decide the number of '#' symbols.

Answer (score 66):

Yes, if you use `*` in your format string, it gets a number from the arguments:

```
printf ("%0*d\n", 3, 5);
```

will print "005".

Keep in mind you can only pad with spaces or zeros. If you want to pad with something else, you can use something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (void) {
    char *s = "MyText";
    unsigned int sz = 9;
    char *pad = "########################################";
    printf ("%.*s%s\n", (sz < strlen(s)) ? 0 : sz - strlen(s), pad, s);
}
```

This outputs `###MyText` when `sz` is 9, or `MyText` when `sz` is 2 (no padding but no truncation). You may want to add a check for `pad` being too short.

Comment: Sorry, @Debanjan, I missed one of the `*` characters. The new version has been checked more thoroughly.

Comment: why does char *pad, has to be so long? I mean ins't it limited by the final output string length

Answer (score 2):

You could write like this :

```
void foo(int paddingSize) {
       printf ("%*s",paddingSize,"MyText");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf( "%.*s", paddingSize, string );
```

For example:

```
const char *string = "12345678901234567890";
printf( "5:%.*s\n", 5, string );
printf( "8:%.*s\n", 8, string );
printf( "25:%.*s\n", 25, string );
```

displays:

```
5:12345
8:12345678
25:12345678901234567890
```

Answer (score -1):

Be careful though - some compilers at least (and this may be a general C thing) will not always do what you want:

```
char *s = "four";
printf("%*.s\n", 5, s); // Note the "."
```

This prints 5 spaces;

```
char *s = "four";
printf("%*s\n", 3, s);  // Note no "."
```

This prints all four characters "four"

Answer (score -2):

better use std::cout

```
#include<iomanip>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
cout << setw(9)                       //set output width
     << setfill('#')                  // set fill character
     << setiosflags(ios_base::right)  //put padding to the left
     << "MyText";
```

should produce:

```
###MyText
```