# Setting field width with a placeholder in C with 'char'

Tags: c++, c

I'm converting my c++ program to c. It's a simple factorial function. I used an interesting method in the c++ program in order to space it less and less each time the function called itself. This is what that looked like:

```
cout << setw( number * 3 ) << "" << "number is: " << number << endl;
```

It's not translating into c as easily as I had hoped. My idea (which is probably incorrect) is

```
char c = "";
printf( "%*c number is: %lo\n", number * 3, c, number);
```

I'm getting an error that says: *warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]*

How would you achieve this same effect in c? I really liked the way I implemented it in c++ and would like to do it in a similar way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable sized padding in printf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133318/variable-sized-padding-in-printf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `C`, you use single quote for one character, you use double quotes for C style strings

So

```
char c = "" ;
```

is wrong.

you should use

```
char c = ' ';
```

Comment: You forgot to mention that he shouldn't be adding the padding manually anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The warning you get has nothing to do with your printing attempts. The warning comes from

```
char c = "";
```

You cannot initialize a character variable with a string literal. If you need a character, initialize it with a character constant

```
char c = ' ';
```

If you need a string, declare it as a pointer or as a character array

```
const char *c = "";
char c[] = "";
```

It really depends on what you are trying to do.

But in reality you don't need that `c` at all. The direct analogue of your C++ code in C would be a mere

```
printf("%*snumber is: %d\n", number * 3, "", number);
```

assuming your `number` is of `int` type.

Answer (score 0):

*How would you achieve this same effect in c?*
Something like:

```
printf("%s: %d", "The number is", number * 3";
```

spaces can be edited into the printf statement, but if you want a char array space you can do it like:

```
char c[]={" "};

printf("%s:%s%d", "The number is", c, number * 3";
```