# How to print a variable length string of a single character

Tags: c, vba, function, c-strings

I have a need to print a variable number of a given character in conjunction with my formatted output. I was looking for something similar or equivalent to the VBA function String(num, char),  but haven't been able to find any. I've written a function to do the job but if there is something built-in that does it I'd love to know. Here's what I have. For the purpose of testing I'm using a sloppy implementation of argv[].

What I want to is print out something like this;

[image]

Here's the rough implementation I've come up with;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char * make_string(int num,  char character)
{
    char *strchars = malloc(num);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        strchars[i] = character;

    return strchars;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", make_string(strlen(argv[i]),'_'));
        printf("%s%c %s\n", make_string(strlen(argv[i]),'_'),'|', argv[i]);
    }
}
```

Is there a library function for printing strings of repeating characters like this?

Comment: Your program leaks memory like like a cargo-net roof in a RAM storm.  It probably doesn't matter for your demo program, but it would be better to make a habit of ensuring that you free all the memory you allocate.

Comment: Also, you must be sure to allow space for a string terminator, and to insert one at the end of each string.

Comment: In any case, the C standard library does not contain a function such as you are looking for.

Comment: Why go to the trouble/expense of allocating memory and forming a new string? Why not just directly print the character repeatedly in a loop?

Comment: Check this example. I think this will be useful.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133318/variable-sized-padding-in-printf

Comment: @John Bollinger ROFL. on the Cargo-Net analogy. I fixed the memory leak and added a '\0' to the string before the return. checked it in valgrind and it came back clean.  Thanks for the reminder. I'm still learning.

Comment: @UmamaheshP Thanks for the example. That works! And with much less code and no need for a function or a loop. That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Credit for this answer goes to UmamaheshP for pointing me in the right direction with a comment.  This is what I was looking for and was adapted from an example he linked to.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    char *pad = "________________";
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        printf ("%.*s\n%.*s%c %s\n", strlen(argv[i]), 
            pad,strlen(argv[i]), pad, '|', argv[i]);
}
```