# NSLog(@"%-20s %-32s", [theCard.name UTF8String]) %-32s means?

Tags: objective-c

I am studying Objective-C, I know NSLog to print out, But I am lost with this %-20s %-32s.

What is this -20s and -32s doing here

```
  -(void) list
    {
    NSLog (@"======== Contents of: %@ =========", bookName);
    for ( AddressCard *theCard in book )
    NSLog (@"%-20s %-32s", [theCard.name UTF8String],
    [theCard.email UTF8String]);
    Array Objects 339
    NSLog (@"==================================================");
    }
    @

====================================
|                                  |
| Tony Iannino                     |
| tony.iannino@techfitness.com     |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
| O O                              |
====================================
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [String Padding in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276827/string-padding-in-c)

Comment: no worries, I have got the answer from Joni. Thanks anyhow. happy to close this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are printf formatting specifiers to print a string of 20 and 32 characters, filled with blanks on the right.

```
% start of the specifier
- align the field to left instead of right
32 width of field
s type of field is string
```

Full documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

`NSLog()` understands `printf()` format strings with some extensions, so you can look up in the [documentation of `printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html) what this does:

> Each conversion specification is introduced by the '%' character [XSI]
>   or by the character sequence "%n$" [...]
>
> - Zero or more flags  [...]
> - An optional minimum field width [...]
> - An optional precision [...]
> - An optional length modifier [...]
> - A conversion specifier character that indicates the type of conversion to be applied.
>
> [...]
>
> The flag characters and their meanings are:
>
> [...]
>
> -: The result of the conversion shall be left-justified within
>   the field. The conversion is right-justified if this flag is not
>   specified.  [...]
>
> The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>
> [...]
>
> s: The
>   argument shall be a pointer to an array of char. Bytes from the array
>   shall be written up to (but not including) any terminating null byte.
>   If the precision is specified, no more than that many bytes shall be
>   written. If the precision is not specified or is greater than the size
>   of the array, the application shall ensure that the array contains a
>   null byte.
>
> [...]

So, what this conversion does is printing an array of `const char`, printing 20 and 32 characters, respectively, padding it with spaces to the right in order left justufication to take effect.