# objective-c right padding

Tags: objective-c, string, padding

hello all hope someone can help with that. I was browsing the net and nothing really seems to make sense :S

so I have a string lets say:
`"123"` and I would like to use a function like:

```
padr("123", 5, 'x')
```

and the result should be:

```
"123xx"
```

Sorry but Objective-C is a nightmare when dealing with strings :S

Comment: possible duplicate of [String Padding in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276827/string-padding-in-c?rq=1)

Comment: The way I see it printf does not produce a NSString but I might be wrong

Comment: A document application such as Dash makes it much easier to find API methods. Just by entering "padd" I see the method.

Answer (score 3):

You could create your own method to take the initial string, desired length, and padding character (as I was starting to do & also described in a few similar questions)

Or you could use the NSString method Apple already provides ;)

```
NSString *paddedString = [@"123" 
                           stringByPaddingToLength: 5 
                           withString: @"x" startingAtIndex:0];
```

See [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByPaddingToLength:withString:startingAtIndex:) for this method.

Answer (score 0):

What about the [NSString method  `stringByPaddingToLength:withString:startingAtIndex:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByPaddingToLength:withString:startingAtIndex:).

```
NSString* padr(NSString* string, NSUInteger length, NSString *repl)
{
    return [string stringByPaddingToLength:length withString:repl startingAtIndex:0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableString* padString(NSString *str, int padAmt, char padVal)
{
    NSMutableString *lol = [NSMutableString stringWithString:str];

    while (lol.length < padAmt) {
        [lol appendFormat:@"%c", padVal];
     }

    return lol;

}
```

And the Call

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {


        NSLog(@"%@", padString(@"123", 5, 'x'));


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, easier just to use the Apple `stringByPaddingToLength` method.