# Add leading zeros to a string value in C

Tags: c, string, zero-padding

it's requested that a given string `char input_str[5] = "Hello";` must be padded with leading character = `0`. so the result will have a fixed length of `10` characters: `out_put == "00000Hello"`.

any idea how to do so in C?

Comment: Padded where? In memory? When printing? In same string? In a different one?

Comment: Using the `printf` function family you can 0 pad a string as well as an integer. Have a read of the man page.

Comment: You can use 0 padding but gcc warns that it leads to undefined behavior with `s`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String Padding in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276827/string-padding-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

here you are an example

```
int targetStrLen = 10;           // Target output length  
const char *myString="Hello";   // String for output 
const char *padding="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";

int padLen = targetStrLen - strlen(myString); // Calc Padding length
if(padLen < 0) padLen = 0;    // Avoid negative length

printf("[%*.*s%s]", padLen, padLen, padding, myString);  // LEFT Padding 
printf("[%s%*.*s]", myString, padLen, padLen, padding);  // RIGHT Padding
```

If you have some doubt see this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9741091/3284537
where I extract the code

Comment: This should be a comment or probably a close-as-duplicate vote.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers.

Comment: probably you right but meantime the user get his answer

Comment: The user should have made his own attempt. No effort was shown. It does not help to spoon-feed people who ask "write my code for me".

Comment: I will do but copy paste the code seems to me worst than paste the link